# El resultado no es el esperado

Tags: python, array, numpy

Con este codigo pretendo reordenar un vector de entrada segun "ff.P()". El resultudado  no es el esperado

```
ff.P()=array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])



p=np.array([[1,2],[3,1],[2,-1],[2,5],[0,1],[4,2],[1,0],[3,3],[0,4],[2,2],[3.5,1],[3.5,5]])

d =[]

for i in range(len(c)):

    for j in range(len(p)):
        if ff.P()[i,:][j]==1:

        d=np.append(d,p[j],axis=0)
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
array([ 1. ,  2. ,  0. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  4. ,  3. ,  1. ,  2. ,
   -1. ,  2. ,  5. ,  4. ,  2. ,  3. ,  3. ,  2. ,  2. ,  3.5,  1. ,
    3.5,  5. ])
```

El deseado es el siguiente:

```
array([[1, 2],[0, 1],[1, 0],[0, 4],[3, 1],[2, -1],[2, 5],[4, 2],[3, 3],[2,2],
[3.5, 1],
[3.5, 5]])
```

Comment: Hola picaro eles, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Supongo que `ff.P()` es una función o método  que retorna `array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])`,  falta definir `c` en el código (`len(c)`), supongo que debe tener la mima longitud que `ff.P()`,  dos en el ejemplo.

Comment: Aparte de esto, no termino de entender de dónde sale la salida esperada que muestras, entendería que fuera `array([array([[1., 2.], [0., 1.], [1., 0.], [0., 4.]]), array([[3., 1.], [ 2., -1.], [2., 5.], [4., 2.], [3., 3.], [2., 2.], [3.5, 1. ], [3.5, 5. ]])])` pero no la que tú muestras, podrías explicar de dónde sale es salida esperada para el ejemplo que muestras?¿O la salida esperada es la que muestro yo?

Comment: Hola, Gracias por responder. Si "c" tiene la misma longitud que ff.P().

Comment: La salida esperada la genero con un codigo qur trabaja con listas. Estoy tratando de mejorar el rendimiento, trabajando con "numpy" utilizando array en ves de listas

Comment: el metodo ff.P() retorna array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])

Comment: A lo que me refiero es a cómo partiendo de `array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])` y `p=np.array([[1,2],[3,1],[2,-1],[2,5],[0,1],[4,2],[1,0],[3,3],[0,4],[2,2],[3.5,1],[3.5,5]])` terminamos con `array([array([[ 1.,  2.],
   [ 3.,  1.],
   [ 2., -1.],
   [ 2.,  5.]]),
   array([[0. , 1. ],
   [4. , 2. ],
   [1. , 0. ],
   [3. , 3. ],
   [0. , 4. ],
   [2. , 2. ],
   [3.5, 1. ],
   [3.5, 5. ]])], dtype=object)` ¿Cuál es la lógica del filtro para obtener esa salida? Entendería la que pongo arriba yo, pero no esta.

Comment: Perdon! he puesto mal la salida! de hecho es el mismo "p"

Comment: si utilizo "d.append(p[j])" en ves de "d=np.append(d,p[j],axis=0)" el resultado es: [[1, 2],
 [0, 1],
 [1, 0],
 [0, 4],
 [3, 1],
 [2, -1],
 [2, 5],
 [4, 2],
 [3, 3],
 [2, 2],
 [3.5, 1],
 [3.5, 5]] Estoy buscando que el mismo sea un array y no una lista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy permite el indexado booleano, por lo que puedes simplemente hacer:

```
d = np.vstack(p[filtro == 1.] for filtro in ff.P())
```

Para reproducirlo:

```
# Esto solo es para emular la llamada a  tu función
from types import SimpleNamespace
ff = SimpleNamespace(P=lambda: np.array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
                                         [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.]
                                        ]))

import numpy as np    


p = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 1], [2, -1], [2, 5], [0, 1], [4, 2],
              [1, 0], [3, 3], [0, 4], [2, 2], [3.5, 1], [3.5, 5]])

d = np.vstack(p[filtro == 1.] for filtro in ff.P())
```

> ```
> >>> p
>
> [[ 1.   2. ]
>  [ 0.   1. ]
>  [ 1.   0. ]
>  [ 0.   4. ]
>  [ 3.   1. ]
>  [ 2.  -1. ]
>  [ 2.   5. ]
>  [ 4.   2. ]
>  [ 3.   3. ]
>  [ 2.   2. ]
>  [ 3.5  1. ]
>  [ 3.5  5. ]]
> ```

Comment: Estoy totalmente sorprendido y agradecido por lo simple de tu respuesta!